# continuity of inclusion map in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $(E, d|_{E \times E})$ be a subspace of $(X,d)$. Let $i : E \to X$ be the inclusion map, defined by setting $i(x) : = x$ for all $x \in E$. Show that $i$ is continuous.

I know that if for any open subset $Z$ of $X$, $i^{-1}(Z)$ is an open set in $E$, then $i$ is continuous. Let $Z$ be any open subset of $X$. If $Z$ does not contain any $i(x)$, then $i^{-1}(Z) = \emptyset \subset E$, and we know that $\emptyset$ is open in $E$.

Thus, suppose that there exists $i(x) \in Z$. Since $Z$ is open, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_X(i(x), \epsilon) \subset Z$. This implies that $B_E(i(x), \epsilon) \subset Z$. If I know that $i^{-1}(B_E(i(x), \epsilon))$ is open, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B_E(x, \delta) \subset i^{-1}(B_E(i(x), \epsilon))$, and this actually conclude that $i$ is continuous. But how do we know that $i^{-1}(B_E(i(x), \epsilon))$ is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$i^{-1}(B_X(i(x)),\epsilon)$ is nothing but $B_E(x,\epsilon)$, the ball of radius $\epsilon $ around $x$ in the space $E$, hence it is open.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{-1}(Z)=Z\cap X$, which is open by definition of the subspace topology.

In fact, one way to define the subspace topology is as the coarsest topology that makes the inclusion continuous.

Comment: Of course that proof assumes you already know that the subspace metric induces the subspace topology. Otherwise that part has to be proved as well.

Comment: @celtschk  good point.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in E$ and $\varepsilon>0$ we take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and observe that

$$\forall y \in E: (d_E(x,y) < \delta) \to \left( d(i_E(x),i_E(y))=d(x,y) < \varepsilon \right)$$

and so $i_E$ is continuous at $x$, as required.